# How can prove that inverse of transition matrix shows path equations between digraph's nodes?

Tags: matrices, graph-theory, matrix-equations, matrix-calculus, algebraic-graph-theory

If matrix T represents transitions between all nodes in digraph G, how can prove that the inverse of T represents path equation of digraph G?

For example, consider following transition matrix:

$$
T= \left( \begin{array}{ccc}
0 & a & b & 0\\
0 & 0 & 0 & c \\
0 & 0 & 0 & d \\
0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \end{array} \right) \rightarrow T^{-1} = \sum\limits_{i=0}^n T^i =  \left( \begin{array}{ccc}
0 & a & b & ac+bd\\
0 & 0 & 0 & c \\
0 & 0 & 0 & d \\
0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \end{array} \right)
$$

Element(1,4) of inverse of T represents path equation from node 1 to node 4.
We need prove mentioned example in general.

Thanks a lot.

Comment: That matrix isn't the inverse

Comment: I edit the question. Now can you help me prove the mentioned example in general?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$T$ is all the connections of length 1 (ie edge connections). $T^2$ is all the connections of length two. In general $T^n$ is all the connections of length $n$. Adding these together gives all the connections from 1 to $n$.

$T^{-1}=\sum^{\infty}_{n=1}T^n$ is then the sum of all possible path lengths connecting the various point pairs.

Comment: Thank you! Could you please introduce me a reference like a book or a paper about mentioned issue?

Comment: There's a good description of something very related and similar [here in the wikipedia article on Markov chains](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Markov_chain#Example)